# Why is the controller not redirecting to proper view in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

In the below snippet, I have an html form in my example page with the form's action attribute set to exampleController URI in my Routes as follows:

htmlPage.blade.php

```
<form action="/exampleController" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    // rest of form stuff goes here
</form>

@if(isset($result))
    <table>
        <td>{{ $result }}</td>
    </table>
 @endif
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/gotoform', 'PageController@showform');
Route::post('/exampleController', 'PageController@processData');
```

Controller.php

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function showform()
   {
        return view('htmlPage');
   }
   }
   public function processData(Request $request)
   {
       $result = $request['htmlInputData'];
       return view('htmlPage')->with(compact('result');
   }
}
```

Everything is fine from here and data is being processed and displayed correctly on the page but I was wondering why the URL address the controller returned for the `$result` variable is `mydomain.com/exampleController` and not `mydomain.com/htmlPage` which is the html page responsible for displaying the results of the operation.

Also, since the resulting URL address is `mydomain.com/exampleController` (which is not what I expected), its returning the following error when manually refreshed:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:
```

Can somebody please enlighten me what did I missed? 
thanks in advance.

EDIT:
by changing to `Route::any` the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error has gone away but still the URL returned by the controller is not right.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you return a View (`view('htmlPage')`).

if you want to access this url `mydomain.com/htmlPage` you need to redirect not load a View.

Use this  `return redirect(url('/htmlPage'))->with(compact('result');`

In order to load this successfully you need to have another route :

```
Route::get('/htmlPage', 'PageController@loadhtmlPage');
```

and also to load the view in this url you have to do this in your controller:

```
public function loadhtmlPage(Request $request)
{
    return view('htmlPage');
}
```

Comment: it will result in a 404 when doing return redirect from the controller. but accessing it directly is ok.

Comment: its because you don't have the route in your routes.php

Comment: there is a separate route to access the form page and a separate route to handle form processing

Comment: yes but you want to go to another route (/htmlpage) after submiting the form

Comment: I have updated the question above to show my routes to show the form page.

Comment: okay use the return statement from my answer, add the route from my answer in your routes.php and also the function in your controller

Comment: Have you created PageController file inside Http/Controllers Directory as you have defined PageController@showform in web.php file so please check if it is not please create that controller file and make it working.

Comment: Ok if works for you then i will post as an answer in proper manner so will helpful to others also.